# UDP socket recv buffer size

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

Does this `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max` value give overall UDP recv buffer size or per port/socket udp buffer size ? 
How to set buffer size per UDP port/socket ?

Comment: You set it per socket with `setsockopt()` and `SO_RCVBUFSIZ`.

Comment: Thanks. what about value from here /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max ?

Comment: That's the maximum value you can set it to. It's documented.